# jQuery dialog(any type) creation with new dropdown menu items (includes AJAX request)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to create a `dialog box containing dropdown menu's`. This dialog box will pop up `on a button click event in jQuery`. I do not have any HTML content prior and so, this will be on the fly. `All the dropdown items will be predefined/hard-coded`. So far I have written this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var button = $('<div class="toolbar content-header-toolbar"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Start Job</a></div>');

        $("a", button).click(
            function()
            {
                $('<div></div>').dialog({
                            modal: true,
                             title: "Confirmation",
                            open: function() {
                            var markup = 'USER SELECTION';
                            $(this).html(markup);
                    },
                    buttons: {
                            Ok: function() {
                             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                            }
                    }); 
               }
        );  
    }
);
```

This gives me a dialog box with a title `USER SELECTION` and a button `OK to close the dialog box.`

How do I `create dropdown menus in such a dialog box?` Once again, I `do not have any HTML` content before. Also I want to fill the dropdown list write here in the code as they will be predefined. For example, one dropdown will be of `user profile` which will have either `profile 1, profile 2 or profile 3 as their selection`.

The expected output is show below:

[image]

The above expected output image shows 3 dropdown menus `SELECT A JOB`, `TEST PROFILE` and `EXPERIMENTS`. User will then select values for these menus and hit the `RUN` button if desired.

Once the `RUN` button is hit by the user, how do I send the `dropdown selected data via an AJAX request`? (maybe something like below will work?):

```
$.ajax({        
            url: 'something.php',
            data: {...dropdown data...}
            type: 'post',             
            success: function(response) {}
});
```

Not an expert of jQuery, JS / AJAX, a good example will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recreated your original example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6150mygp/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toolbar = $("<div>", {
    class: "toolbar content-header-toolbar",
  })
  var button = $("<a>", {
      href: "#"
    })
    .html("Start Job")
    .click(function() {
      var dlg = $("<div>", {
        id: "menuDialog"
      }).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation",
        open: function() {
          var markup = 'USER SELECTION';
          $(this).html(markup);
        },
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });
    }).appendTo(toolbar);
  toolbar.appendTo("body");
});
```

This gives us a working button and that button launches the proper dialog.

Next we need to make the intial Menu Header Links. These will unhide the menus so the user can make their selection.

Here we are with the menus visible and some more work to be done: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6150mygp/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toolbar = $("<div>", {
    class: "toolbar content-header-toolbar",
  });
  var button = $("<a>", {
      href: "#"
    })
    .html("Start Job")
    .click(function() {
      var dlg = $("<div>", {
        id: "menuDialog"
      }).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation",
        open: function() {
          var markup = '<span style="display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center" class="title">USER SELECTION</span>';
          var topMenu = $("<ul>", {
            id: "topMenu",
            style: "margin: 0;"
          });
          topMenu.append("<li data-menu='job'><a href='#'>SELECT A JOB</a></li><li data-menu='profile'><a href='#'>TEST PROFILE</a></li><li data-menu='exp'><a href='#'>EXPERIMENTS</a></li>");
          topMenu.find("li a").on("click", function() {
            var selection = $(this).data("menu");
            console.log("Clicked " + selection);
          });
          markup += '<style>#topMenu li { display: inline-block; width: 33%; list-style: none;} .ui-menu { width: 150px; } ul.subMenu { display: hidden; }</style>';
          markup += topMenu.prop('outerHTML');
          var jobMenu = $("<ul>", {
              class: "subMenu"
            }),
            proMenu = jobMenu.clone(),
            expMenu = jobMenu.clone();
          jobMenu.attr("id", "jobMenu")
            .css({
              width: "33%",
              display: "inline-block"
            })
            .append("<li>Android Phone</li><li>iOS Phone</li><li>iOS Tablet</li>")
            .menu();
          proMenu.attr("id", "proMenu")
            .css({
              width: "33%",
              display: "inline-block"
            })
            .append("<li>Profile 1</li><li>Profile 2</li><li>Profile 3</li>")
            .menu();
          expMenu.attr("id", "expMenu")
            .css({
              width: "33%",
              display: "inline-block"
            })
            .append("<li>Experiment 1</li><li>Experiment 2</li><li>Experiment 3</li>")
            .menu();
          $(this).html(markup).append(jobMenu, proMenu, expMenu);
        },
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        },
        width: "640"
      }).css("font-size", "85%");
      return false;
    })
    .appendTo(toolbar);
  toolbar.appendTo("body");
  $("body").find("#topMenu li").on("click", function() {
    var selection = $(this).data("menu");
    console.log("Clicked " + selection);
  });
});
```

You did not mention if a CSS can be used, so I have avoided that as well as avoiding any initial HTML. As you can see, it's easier to build elements in jQuery, assign UIs to them, and then append them. Since we have no DOM upon loading, this allows us to assign the various code and structure that is needed.

The following code still leaves you with some things to fix or adjust on your own. Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6150mygp/4/

**jQuery**

```
function showMenu(m, o) {
  $(".subMenu").hide();
  console.log("Showing #" + m + "Menu");
  console.log("Setting #" + m + "Menu position to: { my: 'left top', at: 'right top', of: '#" + o + "' }");
  $("#" + m + "Menu").menu({
    position: {
      my: "left top",
      at: "right top",
      of: "#" + o
    }
  }).show();
}

function enableRun() {
  if (Object.keys(jobOptions).length === 3) {
    console.log("All options set. ", jobOptions);
    $("#run").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
  }
}
var jobOptions = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toolbar = $("<div>", {
    class: "toolbar content-header-toolbar",
  });
  var button = $("<a>", {
      href: "#"
    })
    .html("Start Job")
    .click(function() {
      var dlg = $("<div>", {
        id: "menuDialog"
      }).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation",
        open: function() {
          var markup = '<span style="display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center" class="title">USER SELECTION</span>';
          var topMenu = $("<ul>", {
            id: "topMenu",
          });
          var ml1 = $("<li>", {
              'data-menu': ''
            }),
            ml2 = ml1.clone(),
            ml3 = ml1.clone();
          ml1.html("SELECT A JOB").attr("data-menu", "job").appendTo(topMenu);
          ml2.html("TEST PROFILE").attr("data-menu", "pro").appendTo(topMenu);
          ml3.html("EXPERIMENTS").attr("data-menu", "exp").appendTo(topMenu);
          topMenu.menu({
            select: function(e, ui) {
              console.log("#topMenu Item Selected.");
              showMenu(ui.item.data("menu"));
            }
          });
          markup += '<style>#topMenu { width: 480px; margin: 10px auto; }\r\n#topMenu li { display: inline-block; width: 138px; list-style: none;}\r\n#jobMenu li, #proMenu li, #expMenu li { padding-left: 20px; }</style>';
          markup += topMenu.prop('outerHTML');
          var jobMenu = $("<ul>", {
              class: "subMenu"
            }),
            proMenu = jobMenu.clone(),
            expMenu = jobMenu.clone();
          jobMenu.attr("id", "jobMenu")
            .append("<li>Android Phone</li><li>iOS Phone</li><li>iOS Tablet</li>")
            .menu({
              select: function(e, ui) {
                ui.item.append("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check'></span>");
                jobOptions['job'] = ui.item.text();
                enableRun();
              }
            });
          proMenu.attr("id", "proMenu")
            .append("<li>Profile 1</li><li>Profile 2</li><li>Profile 3</li>")
            .menu({
              select: function(e, ui) {
                ui.item.append("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check'></span>");
                jobOptions['profile'] = ui.item.text();
                enableRun();
              }
            });
          expMenu.attr("id", "expMenu")
            .append("<li>Experiment 1</li><li>Experiment 2</li><li>Experiment 3</li>")
            .menu({
              select: function(e, ui) {
                ui.item.append("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check'></span>");
                jobOptions['experiment'] = ui.item.text();
                enableRun();
              }
            });
          jobMenu.hide();
          proMenu.hide();
          expMenu.hide();
          $(this).html(markup).append(jobMenu, proMenu, expMenu);
        },
        buttons: [{
          id: "run",
          text: "Run",
          class: "ui-state-disabled",
          disabled: true,
          click: function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'something.php',
              data: jobOptions,
              type: 'post',
              success: function(response) {
                alert("Job is running.");
              }
            });
          }
        }, {
          id: "cancel",
          text: "Cancel",
          click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }],
        width: "640"
      }).css("font-size", "85%");
      return false;
    })
    .appendTo(toolbar);
  toolbar.appendTo("body");
  $("body").on("click", "ul#topMenu li", function() {
    var selection = $(this).data("menu");
    console.log("Clicked " + selection);
    showMenu(selection, $(this).attr("id"));
  });
  $(":button:contains('Run')").prop("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disable");
});
```

We now have a lot going on in the script. `showMenu()` shows the menu we have selected from `#topMenu`. It does this by first hiding all the menus and then just showing us the one we're working with.

I set the Run button to be disabled until we have enough settings. the `enableRun()` checks if there are 3 keys in `jobOptions` object, if there are it enables the Run button.

When Run is finally clicked and executed, this can execute AJAX using the collected data object. Your PHP script will receive it in post and you can access them like so:

```
$j = $_POST['job'];
$p = $_POST['profile'];
$e = $_POST['experiment'];
```

As far as I can see, that does all the things you wanted. It would be much easier to do with a HTML layout already in hand. It makes setting options much easier in my opinion. Also, I suspect if you built all the elements via jQuery and did not hard code any HTML via `html()` or `append()`, you'd be able to draw it with less code. I suspect this is also not the only way to do it.

If you have questions, let me know in the comments.

Comment: This definitely answers my question and a good learning example for me. However, looks like the place where I want to use this script does not support certain things and so I am not able to get certain drop downs. If we can chat, I can share my credentials for the tool in which I am trying to use this script and give you a sort of example - that might help us out.

Comment: @PratikJaiswal gladly.

Comment: Twisty and I spent almost a day to get this script working on my external tool. Great learning and he got me sorted out!